# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Closes then Opens on Click in Safari/iPhone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, joomla3.0, nav

**Site:** http://dev.shareandcare.org

**Brief:** Bootstrap Menu + Joomla 3 has been such a pain to get working. I have resolved several issues and now a issue exists with the sandwich menu on iOS/iPhone and Safari (under 768 browser width) where when you open the mobile menu, it closes then reopens.

Here is a video of the issue: http://sendvid.com/og6wuedv

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same issue minus the Joomla. I've tried a number of things but have found no resolution as of yet. Something is being called twice :/

Comment: I just noticed the nav in your site link works as expected. How did you resolve this?